# Is it possible to customise a existing error/exception in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

My controller is catching the following error in a observed case

```
#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2:: Error: Duplicate entry 'xyz1' for key 'abc.xyz': INSERT INTO'abc' (<insert statement which is throwing the error>
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to customize this exception such that it also includes the existing entry because of which the error of duplication is being thrown..

It might seem redundant to modify an existing standard error/exception, but I need it to avoid repetition of same logic in every controller to handle this error in order to fulfill the requirement as stated above.

**Update 1**
Expected output:

Whenever the following exception is thrown, an alternate error message has to be sent as exception which will be something like this..

```
{Message: "Error caused due to Duplicate entry 'xyz1' for key 'abc.xyz'", existing_abc_with_same_xyz: Abc.find_by(xyz: "xyz1"}
```

Something like overriding/overloading the existing error statement.

There are many locations where this error is being handled because of Abc being a `nested_attribute` for many other resources... Because of which I will have to customise in every location, which I feel as redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message). It provides human readable error in the model

```
class Abc < ApplicationRecord
  validates :xyz, uniqueness: true
end
```

And then customize message in locales

Also it's possible to use `:message` key

```rb
validates :xyz,
  uniqueness: {
    message: ->(_, data) do 
      "Error caused due to Duplicate entry #{data[:value]} for key 'abc.xyz'. Existing Abc with same xyz: #{Abc.find_by(xyz: data[:value]}"
    end
  }
```

Please see [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message)

Comment: Thanks @mechnicov,  Yes I agree, the above validation will definitely return a human readable error.. but my requirement is to modify the error to contain the entry which is causing the duplication

Comment: Regarding "And then customize message in locales".. there are many locations where this error is being handled because of  Abc being a nested_attribute for many ... Because of which I will have to customise in every location which I feel as redundant. So I was searching if there is an one shot fix for this.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to validate with a custom validation class.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates_with MyUniquenessValidator
end
```

to save yourself time and effort, your custom validation class can inherit from the standard uniqueness validator, and just overwrite the pieces you need to customize.

```rb
# my_uniqueness_validator.rb
class MyUniquenessValidator < ActiveRecord::Validations::Uniqueness
  def validates_each # overwrites standard method
     # in here, copy the standard method, but change the line
     # where it looks for a duplicate to return the id of the duplicate
     # and change the line where it says record.errors.add(...) to include the id of the
     # record that is being duplicated
  end
end
```

You can probably find the standard ActiveRecord uniqueness validator to study by opening activerecord in your editor: `bundle open activerecord` and then navigate to 'lib/activerecord/validations/uniqueness.rb'. This is where to find it in Rails 7, it will be similar in Rails 5.